# Button code preference

Tags: javascript

Im new to Javascript and this site. Below are 2 codes (only HTML, normal i work with external js files) which deliver a button what you can click for a date. I was wondering which code has the preference amongst the developers and is there any advantage from 1 another? The way i see it is that adding a function is overkill.

**Code 1**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">The time is?</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

**Code 2**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">The time is?</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First way is horrible to read or maintain.

Comment: The function is mainly used to remove redundancy of the code.And you can use it wherever you want

Comment: They are both inline attribute event handlers which in general are discouraged. Using `addEventListener()` is the prefered way.

Comment: Both are awful. `onclick` attributes should have died when the millennium turned. (This is a question which will attract opinionated answers)

Answer (score 0):

The second one is way better, you are separating the js from the html.

If you have two buttons with the same function, it will be easier to avoid duplicated code and to maintain with the second version!

For example if you want to change the behaviour of your buttons, you won't have to modify your html and be able to change the beviour every where at once.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the correct answer here is neither of both.

To write maintainable and readable code, the best practice is to have a complete separation between HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Making the assumption that "it's only one line", is pretty dangerous, as one line quickly becomes two and so on. It's better to always use the same rules instead of making exceptions for one-liners.

Personally, I would write HTML like this:

```
<button class="time-button"></button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

In script.js, you can then attach an event listener like this:

```
// Note that querySelector might not be supported in really old browsers
var timeButton = document.querySelector('.time-button');
var demoParagraph = document.getElementById('demo');

// Or attachEvent for IE < 11
timeButton.addEventListener('click', timeFunction);

/**
 * Here you can write some beautiful comments about the function
 */
function timeFunction (eventData) {
   demoParagraph.innerHTML = new Date().toISOString();
}
```

In case you write it like that you can start listening (addEventListener) and stop listening (removeEventListener) whenever you want to.

It's recommended to put the elements in a variable, since looking up an element is pretty slow.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say :

Both are correct depending on what you want to do with it.

First way : OK if the function is short and not complex, no re-use purpose.

Second way : OK if the function is complex, need to be maintained and plus : you can re-use it and avoid code duplication.

Now another approach is to extract javascript methods in another .js file.